# Convert hex to string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ne column in table which has hexadecimal values i want to convert that to string how can i do that?

I have tried this

```
 SELECT
CONVERT(Nvarchar(max), '0x07FD010200000006730A1308320000008990000006730A1308320700008990000002FF006766666666666611FF');
```

But this is not working.

Here i want to convert the value given in single inverted comma.
Please help me.

Comment: For the example you've given, do you know what the string value is supposed to be?

Answer (score 6):

Check [this](https://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/sql-server-convert-a-string-into-a-hex-string-and-back-sql-sqlserver/) for a detailed information of how to achieve this.

Try this

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varbinary(64), '0x16004D616E75623232', 1),
  CONVERT(varchar(64), 0x16004D616E75623232, 1),
  CONVERT(varchar(64), 0x16004D616E75623232, 2);
GO
```

Btw which SQL server are you using?

Comment: I have tried this but this is giving ý symbol as result.

Comment: Did you try the snippet I wrote above?

Comment: Yes i tried but its giving same hex number as result.

Comment: I just have this hex number which i want to convert to string

Comment: This worked for me, just make sure you're adding 0x to the front of it or you'll end up with the problem in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
SELECT CAST(0x54 as varchar(max))
```